# Eclipse RCP MessageConsole: How to allow user to input and handle this listener?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, console, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm writing an eclipse-plugin which creating a new Console. Please see my source code:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IConsoleView consoleView = (IConsoleView) page.showView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);

MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole("CLI", null);
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
consoleView.display(myConsole);

MessageConsoleStream stream = myConsole.newMessageStream();
stream.println("Hello World");
```

The Console "CLI" appeared, but it is not editable by user input. I would like to make user can input directly into the Console by typing in the Console.

And I also want to handle the input but any listener or keybinding.

Anyone know can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `IOConsole` instead! `MessageConsole` is basically a read-only version of `IOConsole`.

From `MessageConsole.createPage(...)`:

```
public IPageBookViewPage createPage(IConsoleView view) {
    IOConsolePage page = (IOConsolePage) super.createPage(view);
    page.setReadOnly();
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Tonny: can you help me on next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476025/how-to-set-the-caret-of-the-ioconsole