# java, readline from a plugin console

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin

To write in the console of the plugin I'm developing I use this method that I found before.
**my work**

```
private static MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {

    if (ConsolePlugin.getDefault() == null)
        return null;
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
        if (name.equals(existing[i].getName())) {
            conMan.showConsoleView(existing[i]);
            return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
        }
    // no console found, so create a new one
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}

public static MessageConsoleStream getMessageStream() {
    MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole("console");
    if (myConsole != null) {
        IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
        return myConsole.newMessageStream();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**that I use like this :**

```
MessageConsoleStream out = Application.getMessageStream();
out.print("AB");
```

now I want to read from the console. **what do I do?**

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `getInputStream()` on the `MessageConsole` instance returned from `findConsole` and going from there. [Read more about the input stream that's returned here.](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/IOConsoleInputStream.html)

Comment: The `MessageConsole` `getInputStream` method always throws `UnsupportedOperationException("Message Console does not support user input")`

Comment: @greg-449 I don't have much experience with eclipse plugins but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10446896/4936696) can be of help